# Is there a way that the client can see what's in $_SESSION?

Tags: php, security, session

I need to put some important data on the `$_SESSION` variable in PHP, and would like to know if this data will be secure. Is a client able to see the information inside of this `$_SESSION` variable? Are there any security implications in storing sensitive data inside of a session?

Comment: It is as secured as your code and servers are secured.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed take you should take steps to make sessions more secure..

1) Use session id by httponly cookie only and disable sessions id's by url..

2) set session_save_path to a new location outside your public index. if you are on a shared host. They cant use session injection to see whats in side your session.
better .. use the database as session handler..

3) disable http methods TRACE, TRACK, HEADER of your webserver, if a attacker can include some java, flash or ajax the user http cookie can also be stolen.

4) lock session on IP useragent or some kind of fingerprint...

5) renew the session_id on all requests to make make session id bruteforce more difficult

Answer (score 2):

No, a client cannot see session data since it is stored server side. However:

If you are on a shared server, it is not impossible for other people sharing the server with you to be able to access it.

Also, session data is tied back to users using a Session ID that is stored in a cookie on the client side. If Bob is able to get Alice's cookie, he will be able to impersonate her.

I guess my answer isn't complete if I don't propose some solutions as well, so :

To solve the first issue, you should store encrypted data in sessions.

To solve the second issue, you should also compare other things like IP address to make sure Bob is not attempting to use someone else's cookie. This way, if Bob steals Alice's cookie, you can then compare Bob's IP with Alice's IP that you have stored in your session, and find a mismatch.

Comment: @user2130148: Glad to help. If it did answer your question, please accept this answer (by clicking the check-mark to the left of the answer).